# Obtener altura en pixeles del navegador que usa el usuario con jQuery

Tags: jquery

Necesito obtener el dato de la altura del navegador del usuario. No me sirve la altura de la pantalla porque en ordenadores de sobremesa se puede redimensionar manualmente.

Estoy probando con esto:

```
$(window).height();
```

Pero el valor que me devuelve es 258px y ya el header tiene 130px. Lo que quiero son las dimensiones del rectángulo que ve el usuario.

Comment: Te refieres a la resolucion del monitor?

Comment: @Einer No, la resolución del navegador con el que está visualizando la web.

Comment: Sobre que ambiente estas probando que `$(window).height()` que te retorna esas dimensiones?

Comment: Cuando te refieres a la altura del navegador, ¿estás hablando de la altura del área visible de la página web en el navegador?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener ese valor con una de estas dos propiedades del objeto window

```
     //Este omite el tamaño de la Barra de Herramientas y las de Scroll
     console.log(window.innerHeight);
     // o este que incluye ambos valores
     console.log(window.outerHeight);
```